# If a continuous function $f$ satisfying $D^+ f(x) \geq a>0, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, where $ a$ is a const, then $f$ is monotone?

Tags: real-analysis

If a continuous function $f$ satisfying $D^+ f(x) \geq a>0,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, where $ a$ is a const, then $f$ is monotone?

Here $D^+ f(x)$ means the Dini's differential, $D^+ f(x)=\lim\sup_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

I think $f$ is monotone, we know that if  $f$ is differentiable, then we can get $f$ is strictly monotone. Now we only know $f$ is continuous, by the definition of $D^+f$, I only got that for any $n>0, \exists x_n \in (x, x+\frac{1}{n}), st \quad f(x_n)-f(x)> \frac{a}{2}(x_n-x)>0$.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ were not monotone increasing, so that there are numbers $c < d$ with $f(c) \ge f(d)$. Let

$$B = \{x \in (c, d) : f(x) > f(c)\}$$

Certainly $B$ is non-empty, since $D^+ f(c) \ge a$; let $b = \sup B$. It follows immediately that $D^+f(b) \le 0$, a contradiction.